# How to select range and update in excel by finding last row in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy paste specific columns from one sheet to another sheet which already has some values:

Example:
Sheet 1 has 20 entries with Columns A to H
Sheet 2 has 100 entries and data filtered and now 50 entries show up
From Sheet 2 select Column C get all the values and copy
Paste it in Sheet 1 from row 21 of column C (as first 2 rows has data)
Again from sheet 2 Column D get all values and copy
Paste it in Sheet 2 from row 21 of column D

From Column C to Column H, remove duplicate entries

I am trying to SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy and PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

```
iRowCount1 = objASheets.UsedRange.Rows.Count
iRowCount2 = objBSheets.UsedRange.Rows.Count
objASheets.Range("$O$2:O").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
objBSheets.Range("$C$2:C").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
objASheets.Range("J$2:J").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
objBSheets.Range("$D$2:D").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False
objBSheets.Range("$G$2:G").Value = "FAIL"
objBSheets.Range("$H$2:H").Value = "Not found"
```

I want to be able to parameterize iRowCount1 and iRowCount2 into the range function, get the list updated and remove duplicates.

First 10 rows (ignore the 1st row as its header) exists in the file, next 13 rows are added out of which needs to be removed from bottom half and not from top.

[image]

Comment: You aren't using `Range()` correctly - where's the last row you want to paste to? What have you tried, there are a bunch of ways to get the last row via VBA. (You'll need to eventually do, like `objASheets.Range("$O$2:$O$" & iRowCount1)...`)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I know I am not using range function correctly. How can I attach sample excel file?

Comment: I have added the image of excel here, on the ones in blue is existing entries, yellow ones are added out of which red ones are identified and removed as duplicates. How to achieve this?

Comment: I find your question quite hard to follow as it seems you have several requirements/Questions inside? If so maybe you should make several short and clear questions instead of this one